# Required package couldn't be found in any version symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

**Hey** 
  I am facing problem in Symfony2 admin panel generation , My version of Symfony is 2.5 and here are my issues while installing **Sonata admin bundle**

> ```
> Problem 1
> - Installation request for symfony-cmf/standard-edition 1.1.x-dev -> satisfi
> able by symfony-cmf/standard-edition[1.1.x-dev].
>  - symfony-cmf/standard-edition 1.1.x-dev requires sonata-project/doctrine-ph
> pcr-admin-bundle 1.1.* -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>  -A typo in the package name
> -The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
> imum-stability setting
> ```

I searched on it, got some stuff to read but nothing could help. What can be the issue and what is the best suitable solution. Its been 6 days i am stuck with admin panel generation. I am following official documentation, 
The [Backend - Sonata Admin](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/cookbook/creating_a_cms/sonata-admin.html) , its very first statement directed me to [this](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html) , after following this i got those errors. Sorry, for a long story guys but i am helpless.
And while answering kindly do explain me in simple word what the real solution is :)

> Please provide a version constraint for the sonata-project/admin-bundle requirement:

I tried dev-master and dev both, nothing helped me.

Your help will be appreciated :)

here is composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony-cmf/standard-edition",
    "homepage": "http://cmf.symfony.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony CMF Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Symfony CMF Community",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/symfony-cmf/standard-edition/contributors"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.1.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "1.2.*",
        "symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "nelmio/alice": "1.*",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "liip/functional-test-bundle": "1.0.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.1-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your composer.json file?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer you to follow installation instructions on official Sonata Admin site: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html

Add this to composer.json:
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.*@dev"

Comment: After writing this statement in my file i run composer.phar install , still same issue it is reporting !

Comment: Did you remove "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "1.1.*"?

Comment: No i didn't its there

Comment: post your composer.json

Comment: how to attach my file in comment ?